# Find the closest value in an array of floats?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, double

I have an Array of floats. 
I have another float.

I wish to loop through the array and to find the index of it with the value closest to my other float. How would I do this?

Comment: I saw several similar questions but I thought dealing with floats might change the logic involved slightly.

Comment: _might change the logic_ Can you give an example of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple Code :

```
float x = 2.25;
float closest_value=array[0];
float subtract_result = Math.Abs(closest_value - x) ;

for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (Math.Abs(array[i] - x) < subtract_result)
    {
        subtract_result = Math.Abs(array[i] - x);
        closest_value = array[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution with LINQ:

```
var index = arrayOfFloats
                .Select((i, f) => Tuple.Create(i, Math.Abs(f - myFloat)))
                .OrderBy(t => t.Item2)
                .First().Item1
```

It projects each number in the array to a [index, absolute difference] tuple, sorts by difference and gets the index of the first (least difference) item.

Answer (score 2):

```
var index = Array.IndexOf(array, array.OrderBy(a => Math.Abs(floatNum - a)).First());
```